# Custom Attribute Value not getting in Category Page in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, custom-options, catalog, custom-attributes

I have created `is_freeshipping` attribute it's a `boolean` (`Yes/No`), and it's showing while product editing in Admin Panel.

And I am getting its value successfully on the Product page, But Category page returning `false` (No) even though it is `true`(Yes).

I tried to get this value by below code.

```
<?php $isFreeShipping = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('is_freeshipping')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Is it the correct procedure? Please suggest me how to get the value of a custom attribute in Category Page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please cross check your `attribute` `is_freeshipping` have the flag Use in `product listing` set to **Yes**. After setting the flag you need to do `reindex` product flat index if `Flat catalog` is `enabled`.

[image]

Comment: checking........

Comment: Thank you. now working. is it mandatory? for showing category page?

Comment: Yes, is it required If you want to get attribute value in product listing page @magentotwo

Comment: Can't believe it was something this simple. Nice and easy answer!